# Update XBMC library from Python script

Tags: python, request, xbmc, kodi

I'm trying to write a script that will run the 'update library' command on my XBMC.

When I try to run:

```
url = 'http://root:libreelec@%IP_ADDRESS%:12345/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "VideoLibrary.Scan"}'
r = requests.get(url)
```

I see that the library is been updated but I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 473, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

I have tried to modify the code to:

```
    url = 'http://root:libreelec@%IP_ADDRESS%:12345/jsonrpc?'
    data = json.dumps({"request": {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "VideoLibrary.Scan"}})
    r = requests.get(url, params=data)
```

but it doesn't seems to work, meaning I don't see the library updated.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who 'root' in the URL? Everything is much simple:

```
url = 'http://libreelec:12345/jsonrpc'
data = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "VideoLibrary.Scan", "id": "1"}
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

The `/json` endpoint accepts POST as well, and `request.post` will process a `dict` into a proper JSON request for you.

Comment: I'm still getting the same result, XBMC library is been updated and also I get the error message. any ideas?

Comment: I forgot about "id" parameter (blindly copy-pasted JSON from your post). Now the JSON payload is correct, but I cannot tell about other parts like Kodi settings (you need to enable remote controlling of Kodi) or JSON-RPC endpoint address. You should check those yourself.